# Returning a variable or a return code from a function

Tags: design, python, functions

Let assume that we have a `main()` function in which we call a `createDirectory()` function.
In Python for instance, the code would be:

```
def main():
    # Do some stuff
    createDirectory(myPath)
    # Do some more stuff
```

To re-use our created directory, I can see at least two ways:

- either the `createDirectory()` function returns 0 in case of success, 1 if it fails to create the directory.
  If the operation succeeds, we know that we can use `myPath` directly later.
- or it returns the path to the directory in case of success and `None` if it fails.

My questions are:

1. are there any specific names for those two styles: returning a return code (fail, success, etc.) or returning an actual useful value (the path to our created directory in my example)?
2. Are there any clear benefits choosing one or the other style?
   I usually return meaningful and useful values rather than return codes but I would be interested in knowing why people use the other style.

Comment: Both styles seem rather poor in Python. Why not raise an exception on failure?

Comment: I used Python to describe that case just because I wanted to keep the example simple but I would obviously raise an exception in Python for that. My question is rather about the general case.

Comment: Then why would you tag Python to the question? It's far from obvious. We're not in your head. The question isn't even answerable in the general case, it entirely depends on the language and the paradigm you're using.

Comment: I tagged it with Python because it's the language I used to describe the example but I specified "In Python *for instance*" so I thought people would understand that it's not a Python-specific question. I'm not asking for a fixed answer working in all situations, just some reasons to choose one style over the other. If it depends on the paradigm you use, your answer can be paradigm-specific :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error codes are basically what you use when you really don't have any other choice. Like when using a really low level language where creating new data structures or throwing exceptions is either a bother or taxing on resources.

The same old, same old regarding "program for people, not computers" holds here too. Be as helpful as possible to the developer who is going to get your errors and needs to debug the code that caused them. Error codes are obscure and magic and need to be looked up in docs/memorized. Data structures representing results and exceptions with good types/messages are self-documenting.

The answer really IS unanswerable in the general case though, as was stated in the comments. As always, do what's idiomatic in the language and team you're currently working in.